# Assign a vector of object values from arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, object

```
class block
{
     private:
          int xPos;
          int yPos;
};

 vector<block> stoneBlocks;

 int stoneBlockXpos[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
 int stoneBlockYpos[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

Basically, what I want to do is to assign the `xPos` and `yPos` the values of the arrays. What is the easiest way of doing this? I have these arrays in several `if()` statements and they're pretty much the x and y coordinates for the level data of the game I'm making.

The only thinkable solution I can come up with is to put a `for()` loop in each `if()` statement, and then assign the values that way. But, that is not going to be very efficient.

Yes, it's all going to happen in the same method if that's neccessary to know. I'm creating these arrays in a "map creator" I made. It's a separate thing. The only way to write the things done in the creator is by printing the vector numbers to a text document in the format of arrays (one each for x and y) and pasting them in the game project's code.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Is it out of the question to write the level data to an external file, and then read it in to your game when you want to load the level?

Comment: Why do you have them stored in arrays if you want to use them in vectors?

Comment: Why do you want to use a vector ? Are you modifying `stoneBlocks` while the level is being played ?

Comment: @NeilKirk I generate the numbers in a program I made. I thought the easiest way of doing this is printing it in the form of an array and then paste it in the game's code to then somehow assign the vectors in the game the values of the arrays. It's raw text.

Comment: @SirDarius Yes, I am using "stoneBlocks" in the game.

Comment: @AndyG I suppose I can do that. Is it <fstream> you're talking about?

Comment: Can you put this data outside of the code, into a higher level data store somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to initialize the vector ONCE (and you have a C++11 compatible compiler), you can use this type of method:

```
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;

class block
{
public:
    block(int x, int y) : xPos(x), yPos(y) {}
private:
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
};


int main()
{
  static vector<block> stoneBlocks1 { {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3} };
  static vector<block> stoneBlocks2 { {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10} };

  ... 
}
```

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I'm creating the vectors in the beginning of main and passing them throughout the game modifying them constantly.

Comment: @TobiasSundell If the arrays in your if statements never change (the raw starting data), why not change to static vectors?

Comment: @NeilKirk Can you tell me how to do that/what is is? :) I'm quite new to vectors. I've only been programming for 1 year.

Comment: `static const vector<block> stoneBlocks { {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3 }};` is similar to `static const int stoneBlockXpos[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; static const int stoneBlockYpos[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};`

Comment: @TobiasSundell: I have added an example of how you could do this.

Comment: @Neil Kirk I'm using Visual Studio 2010, is it possible that that method only works with C++11 compilator? :( It gives me an a';' error.

Comment: @MatsPetersson All right... Well I thank you all for the help. I tried the other solutions but they gave me lots of errors. I'll figure something out.

Comment: I think MSVS 2012 has C++11 support (enough for this to work), and I'm nearly certain the 2013 has it.

Comment: This should work in VS2012 `static const vector<block> stoneBlocks1 = [](){ vector<block> x; x.push_back(block(1, 1)); etc; return x; }();`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `block` has a constructor taking two `int`s, you could do something like this:

```
std::transform(std::begin(stoneBlockXpos), std::end(stoneBlockXpos),
               std::begin(stoneBlockYpos),
               std::back_inserter(stoneBlocks),
               [](int x, int y) { return block(x, y); });
```

(the same can be done with C++03 but it requires a few auxiliary functions).

Assuming you need to do this often, you can create a small wrapper which does the same operations but also makes sure that both arrays have the correct size, e.g.:

```
template <int Size>
std::vector<block>
makeBlocks(int (&xpos)[Size], int (&ypos)[Size])
{
    std::vector<block> rc;
    std::transform(std::begin(xpos), std::end(xpos),
                   std::begin(ypos),
                   std::back_inserter(rc),
                   [](int x, int y) { return block(x, y); });
    return rc;
}

stoneBlocks = makeBlocks(stoneBlockXpos, stoneBlockYpos);
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `std::transform(std::begin(stoneBlockXpos), std::end(stoneBlockXpos),` in your first example?

Comment: `transform` is so useful.